# Generating the topology of a base in a proper subset of a set?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Let $S$ be a set, $\tau_0$ be a subset of $2^S.$ We want to think of $\tau_0$ as a base for a topology on S. Suppose we have the situation where
$$S_0=\bigcup_{s\in\tau_0}s\subset S.$$ That is, it is a proper subset. Would it make more sense to restrict S to $S_0$ and then generate the topology of $\tau_0$ over the space $S_0,$ or should we simply generate the topology over the space $S?$ The latter is essentially accepting that there will be a gap between $S$ and the "second largest" element of our topology. My assumption is that the former is the correct choice, as in the context I've given, S seems arbitrary (though in my studies, it is a very natural set, namely $S_\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: $\tau_0$ usually won't be a base but a subbase. While generating the topology on $S$, we want to add empty set and $S$ as elements of the topology

Comment: @Jakobian Yes, but is this practice useful? Wouldn't it be more useful to restrict our domain so that the subbase already contains these two sets?

Comment: In practice when it happens that $S_0 \neq S$, the spaces will be pathological enough for you to not care. Anyway the distinction is only superficial. The correct way of generating topology is by first add $\emptyset$ and $S$, then all finite intersectiosn, and finally all unions.

Comment: @Jakobian In the end, will the only differences be the inclusion of $\emptyset, S$ and the definition of the complement? I suppose it would be.

Comment: It'd be equivalent to define topology on this set $S_0$. But the point of $\tau_0$ is to generate topology on $S$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arbitary subset $\tau_0 \subset 2^S$ is in general not a base for a topology on $S$, it is only a *subbase*. In order that  $\tau_0$ is a base for a topology on $S$ we need the following requirement:

> For any two $U_1, U_2 \in \tau_0$ and each $x \in U_1 \cap U_2$, there exists $U_3 \in \tau_0$ such that $x \in U_3 \subset  U_1 \cap U_2$.

But for your question it's fairly irrelevant whether $\tau_0$ is a base for a topology on $S$ or only a subbase.

In fact $\tau_0$ generates a topology on $S$ and there are no open sets strictly between $S_0$ and $S$. But where is the problem here? If you take an arbitary $\tau_0 \subset 2^S$, you can define $\bar \tau_0 = \tau_0 \cup \{S\}$. This new $\bar \tau_0 \subset 2^S$ has the property $\bigcup_{U \in \bar \tau_0 } U = S$ and generates **the same topology** as $\tau_0$.

Comment: Sorry I was abusing the word base, I meant it in the heuristic sense that it generates a topology, that is, it’s a set of subsets of S

Comment: @MilesGould This is precisely what a subbase is.

Comment: Kinda, but the definition is meaningless without a specified base. From my understanding, a subbase is only meaningful with respect to a base.